# Remove last letter from map value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I'm getting this from backend:

```
{"Item":{"userEmail":"b","Username":"bUsername","Push":"sdsdsd","Password":"sdsds","Buddy":{"datatype":"SS","contents":{"Drake":"Drake","Ola":"Ola","b":"b","d":"d"}}}}
```

I use `Object.Keys` to narrow down the `contents` to:

```
Drake,Ola,b,d
```

Which I then `map` to give:

```
[{"id":"Drake"},{"id":"Ola"},{"id":"b"},{"id":"d"}]
```

Which is then used on my Angular Front-end as `.id`. I want to remove the last letter from each value i.e leaving `Drak,Ol` etc. I've tried many ways but have failed, how can I achieve this please so that the `id` has those values?

**EDIT**

I also want to now get that value that was cut AND add it such that the end product will be `[{"id":"Drak",valueThatWasCut:"e"}]`

Comment: Inside your map, just slice the last character of the strings?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vjahd2o0/1/

Comment: So the 2 last elements will be "". Right?

Comment: @adeneo your answer worked, why not put in answer section?

Comment: Because according to your question, you're already doing a mapping to get that array, so there's no need for another map call, just slice the strings in the map call you already have.

Comment: @adeneo Do you have an answer for the EDIT part hopefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the object's keys and build with the short string a new object.

```js
var data = {"Item":{"userEmail":"b","Username":"bUsername","Push":"sdsdsd","Password":"sdsds","Buddy":{"datatype":"SS","contents":{"Drake":"Drake","Ola":"Ola","b":"b","d":"d"}}}},
    ids = Object.keys(data.Item.Buddy.contents).reduce(function (r, k) { 
        var n = k.slice(0, -1);
        return n ? r.concat({ id: n }) : r;
    }, []);

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary contents object and change in that.

Then just set this in the original object. ES6 spread operators would save the rest of data without respecifying all keys and values.

```
let items = {"Item:{"userEmail":"b","Username":"bUsername","Push":"sdsdsd","Password":"sdsds","Buddy":{"datatype":"SS","contents":{"Drake":"Drake","Ola":"Ola","b":"b","d":"d"}}}};
let contents = items.Item.Buddy.contents;

let contentsNew = Object.keys(contents).map((content) => {
    return {[content.substring(0, content.length-1)]: content.substring(0, content.length-1), valueThatWasCut: content[content.length-1]};
});

items = {...items, Item: {...items.Item,Buddy:{...items.Item.Buddy,contents: contentsNew}}};
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like :

```
var arr = [{"id":"Drake"},{"id":"Ola"},{"id":"b"},{"id":"d"}];
var result = arr.map(x => x.id.slice(0,-1));
console.log(result); // [ 'Drak', 'Ol', '', '' ]
```